# Good Risk strategy suggestion?

Tags: risk

I'm looking for good Risk strategy suggestions. I tried a couple of things like conquering smaller and easier continents, going for territories which I have a card for but none of this yielded awesome results.

Any help from a guru? 
Thanks

Comment: Voting to reopen. Risk is a well-established game, there are only a few good answers to this question. I don't see this close reason being relevant at all.

Comment: @freekvd thing is, i get similar answer wherever i ask so i kinda gave up in the question..

Comment: Pertinent meta: [Should we close question that are just "what are good strategy tips for such-and-such game"?](http://meta.boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/86/should-we-close-question-that-are-just-what-are-good-strategy-tips-for-such-and)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[HistoryGamerDotCom](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC_nNoyNZsfTULBuGg9j94Bg) has a 9 part YouTube tutorial on Risk strategy. To (grossly) simplify the content:

1. Aim for a non-isolated, not too large continent in the beginning of the game, e.g. South America
2. Know the chances of winning an attack. Three attackers to two defenders is my preferred ratio, as the chance of victory is high but without wasting resources
3. Keep an eye on people's risk cards, as this is an indication of when people are going to get a large reinforcement influx. As a general rule with many exceptions, try to delay cashing yours in, as the reinforcement count for cashing in risk cards increases over time. Note in the base game you do not gain anything extra from cashing in the risk card of a country you occupy, but I have seen computer versions that do this
4. Diplomacy is key! Regularly make pacts so that you won't be ganged up on. Be willing to give a little to get a little, e.g. you might want to under defend one country to keep one player on side
5. Use your reinforcement move to shore up your weaknesses
6. Don't try to expand too quickly, and don't feel you need to attack every turn. This may leave you vulnerable to a sweeping counter attack